# why the refresh is not stop when get the element in python?

Tags: python

I have a question.
Why the refresh is not stop when I got the url.

The refresh is still running when I got the url.

Thank you all.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
PATH = C:// location of webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
url = '1'
driver.get(url)

print(url)

while True:
   if '2' in url:
   

try:
   driver.get('1')
   print('done')

except:
   break
```

---

```
while True:
   if driver.get('1'):
       print('done')
       break 
   else:
       time.sleep(1)
       driver.refresh()
       print('try to reload')
```

---

```
 with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
 driver.get('https://www.google.com/')

 while True:
 if driver.get('https://www.google.com/'):
       print('done')
       break 

 else:
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.refresh
    print('try to reload')
```

I made the example through google,
I don't know why I get the website of google ,
it is still refreshing.
Thanks

Comment: Can you fix your indention and missing parentheses, backticks, and other  issues so we can understand your code without getting bogged down in the mistakes? Note that you can copy and paste your code as-is, then highlight what you pasted and click the `{}` button in the editor to preserve white space and line feeds.

Comment: As written, this will hit `break` regardless of which path the execution takes (whether or not `driver.get(url)` returns `True` or `False`) Is that intended?

Comment: what you mean :(? @JNevill

Comment: Cheeky. There was a `break `after that `print` before you edited. Now that you've updated the code, what I said is no longer relevant. Once you get this question 1:1 with your real code, let us know.

Comment: Yes, I just deleted the break, but I don't know why the refresh is continue, when got the url? @JNevill

Comment: what module/library is `driver.get(url)` is that selenium? If that `.get()` function doesn't return anything, then it wouldn't be "truthy" enough to ever trigger that `if`. Before the `if` can you toss in a `print(driver.get(url))` and rerun. That may offer some clues.

Comment: I tried, it is showed none.

Comment: What is `driver`? What kind of object is that? Feels like whatever module this is would have guidance for how to wait and how that `.get()` method works. Otherwise we are just guessing at how that thing works.

Comment: I think that driver.get(xxx) is for open the url.

Comment: I get that, but where is that defined? Do you have something like `from selenium import driver` that defines what that is?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `driver.get(url)` doesn't return anything and it shouldn't. `driver` is an instance, `.get(url` is an instance's method, `driver.get(url)` change this `driver` instance but it returns nothing. you've to check if there is something on the page that would show you that the page is loaded properly, you can use `driver.current_url` to get html.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    
driver.get('https://lxml.de/')
while True:    
    if driver.current_url:
        print('driver.current_url != None')
        break
    else:
       print("try to reload the website")
       time.sleep(2)
       driver.refresh()
```

`driver.get('url')` would better be placed out of while loop because there is already `driver.refresh()`

---

```
from selenium import webdriver


#every time you try to get google.com you get yahoo.com 

redirect_dict = {
    'https://www.google.com': 'https://www.yahoo.com',
    'https://www.busy.xxx.com' : 'https://www.yyy.com'
} # here you can add any pairs you want: key is site to replace, value is site to replace with 

while site_to_go := input('what site do you want to visit?: '):
    #here a user's to input 'https://www.google.com' or 'google.com'
    if 'https://www.' not in site_to_go:
        site_to_go = f'https://www.{site_to_go}'
    if site_to_go in redirect_dict.keys():
        break
    else:
        print(f"you entered wrong site [{site_to_go}]\ntry another one\n\n\n")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
# driver = webdriver.Firefox()        # this one won't work for you
driver.get(redirect_dict[site_to_go])
print(f'as you can see there is {redirect_dict[site_to_go]} instead of {site_to_go}')
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248365/discussion-on-answer-by-dmitriy-neledva-why-the-refresh-is-not-stop-when-get-the).